# Toggle fullscreen API with a single button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the fullscreen API working on the click of one button and exiting fullscreen on the click of another button. I would like to have the fullscreen toggle open and close with a single button.

```
 var requestFullscreen = function(ele) {
    if (ele.requestFullscreen) {
        ele.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (ele.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        ele.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (ele.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        ele.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (ele.msRequestFullscreen) {
        ele.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.log('Fullscreen API is not supported.');
    }
};

var exitFullscreen = function() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.log('Fullscreen API is not supported.');
    }
};

var fsDocButton = document.getElementById('fs-doc-button');
var fsExitDocButton = document.getElementById('fs-exit-doc-button');

fsDocButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    requestFullscreen(document.documentElement);
});

fsExitDocButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    exitFullscreen();
});
```

```html
<button id="fs-doc-button">FULLSCREEN</button>
<button id="fs-exit-doc-button">EXIT FULLSCREEN</button>
```

Comment: You can use a boolean for the state of fullscreen on and  off.

Comment: As  Arnaud Gueras said, use a boolean `var fullscreen_status = false;` and check/toggle it in your event listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fsDocButton = $('#fs-doc-button');
fsDocButton.data('toggleState', 'first');

fsDocButton.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).data('toggleState') == 'first'){
        requestFullscreen(document.documentElement);
        $(this).data('toggleState', 'second');
    }
    else{
        exitFullscreen();
        $(this).data('toggleState', 'first');
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        $('#fs-doc-button').data('toggleState', 'second');
    }
});
```

Comment: and what if the user cancels the fullscreen by pressing [esc] ?

Comment: right, attaching a listener to 'fullscreenchange' event is required

Comment: Hey thanks but I keep getting this error in firebug "TypeError: fsDocButton.data is not a function" "fsDocButton.data('toggleState', 'first');"

Answer (score 1):

Others are right in that you need some sort of a boolean to detect weither you should cancel or request the fullscreen.

But none takes into account that your users may cancel the fullscreen mode without using your button.

The only cross-browser way to check if you're in fullscreen already is to check for the `document.fullcreenElement`. If non-null, you're already in fullscreen and should exit it.

```
var isFullScreened = function(){
  return document.fullscreenElement ||
    document.mozFullScreenElement ||
    document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
    document.msFullscreenElement;
};
...
if(isFullScreened()){
  exitFs()
}
else{
  enterFS();
}
```